# Access denied when create sale.order on openerp

Tags: php, database, postgresql, odoo

I want to create sale.order in openerp with the data i have in my other database. My database query is right since i have tried it. And I have tried the create sale.order code is right (the input data was manually added in the code). But when i gathered the code it becomes error `Array ( [faultCode] => AccessDenied [faultString] => Access denied )`. Is it because the create sale.order code can not be looping in while or can not required on config file which is contain other database (not oopenerp's database).
Can someone give me solution? Thank You.

```
<?php
        // Ripcord can be cloned from https://github.com/poef/ripcord
        require_once('ripcord/ripcord.php');

        // Login information
        $url = 'http://localhost:8069';
        $url_auth = $url . '/xmlrp/common';
        $url_exec = $url . '/xmlrpc/object';

        $db = 'openerp';
        $username = 'admin';
        $password = 'admin';

        // Login
        $common = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/common");

        //$common = ripcord::client($url_auth);
        $uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array());


        $models = ripcord::client($url_exec);

        include "config.php";
        $sql = "SELECT so.id as id,
                       so.cust_id,
                       so.numb,
                       p.ktr,
                       p.store_id,
                       so.write_date,
                       p.store_name,
                       p.sales_id
                FROM sales_order so
                INNER JOIN store p on p.store_id = so.store_id
               ";

        $exec = pg_query($sql);

        while ($row = pg_fetch_array($exec)){

            $query = pg_query(
                "SELECT sod.product_id, sod.qty_sales, p.name
                               FROM sales_order_line sod
                               INNER JOIN product p on p.id = sod.product_id
                               WHERE sales_order_id = ".$row['id']
            );

            while ($data = pg_fetch_array($query)) {

                $id = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
                    'sale.order', 'create',
                    array(array(
                        'partner_id' => $row['store_id'],
                        'sales_id' => $row['sales_id'],
                        'order_line' => [array(
                            0, false, array(
                                'product_id' => $data['product_id'],
                                'name' => $data['name'],
                                'qty' => $data['quantity'])
                        )]
                    )));

                var_dump($id);

            }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you `include` the `config.php` which is contain other database (not database in used by your openerp).

Write the config file on the same file :

```
$config = pg_connect("host= 'yourhost' port='yourport' dbname= 'yourdbname' user='yourdbuser' password='yourdbpass' ") or die('Failed');
```